# Index match values from a table

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

I am trying to use an advanced VLOOKUP (index small match) formula in my table, but somehow can't figure out what's wrong, **it only prints one cell**.

I want the formula to print (in list) all the cells from column A, that contain time above 2:00 in column J.

[Link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/186nfBubFtTlgeXDxhnrdbhmEGOYXc_TGIw-20rc2kOI/edit?usp=sharing)

I have attached both a screenshot and a link to my table, please help me out.

[image: Table screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A, I:I>0.08333333333, I:I<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can integrate into my table!

Is there a method to use =index small match in this case?

Comment: I wish I could up vote your answer, but I'm still a newbie in this forum.

Comment: @Shavlen you can accept the answer with the check to mark your question as solved

Comment: Is there a method to use an advanced vlookup function here? =index small match in this case?

Comment: @Shavlen not rly sure what do you mean by "index small match" can you elaborate on it in more detail?